# "pair interfaces: operation not supported" error in docker

Tags: networking, docker, 21.10

I installed Ubuntu 21.10 Server for Raspberry PI, then i installed Docker and used docker-compose to start some containers, but i notice this is not working anymore. Previously i had Ubuntu 20.04 LST and everything was working fine (except the lack of NVME boot support, added in 21.10).

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint fpm-redis-1 on network fpm_default: failed to add the host (veth4f16537) <=> sandbox (veth3eb890a) pair interfaces: operation not supported
```

The issue seams to be kernel related after searching for several hours while trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 6):

According to [release notes for 21.10](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-notes/21951), this should help:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-raspi
```

> Various kernel modules have been moved from the `linux-modules-raspi` package in order to reduce the initramfs size. This results in several applications (most notably [Docker, bug 1947601](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/+bug/1947601)) failing due to missing kernel modules. To work around this:
>
> `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-raspi`

Comment: Can confirm that this fixed the problem on my freshly installed Ubuntu Server 21.10 64bit on Raspberry Pi 4B. There's also an older answer on SO: https://serverfault.com/a/1081511